# Java swing Drag&Drop using many transferhandlers on layers

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I need to handle the transfer of an object where the drop area consists of one JPanel, which has its own transferhandler, and a JLabel which also has its own transferhandler. The label is inside the panel so when I drop something on the label I want the both transferhandlers to be triggered. Is this possible?

This is a test code that I have made to explain the situation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1 ,2));

    JTextField text = new JTextField("This is a text to drag!");
    JPanel dropPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel dropLabel = new JLabel("Drop here");


    text.setSize(30, 10);
    text.setDragEnabled(true);

    dropPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    dropPanel.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(){
        @Override
        public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
            System.out.println("Dropped on panel");
            return true;
        }

        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
            return true;
        }
    });


    dropLabel.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(){
        @Override
        public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
            System.out.println("Dropped on label");
            return true;
        }

        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
            return true;
        }
    });


    dropPanel.add(dropLabel);
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(dropPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer would have you calling the `TransferHandler` of the other component manually, but this might be undesirable as one the properties of the `TranferSupport` is the reference to the component which triggered the event

Comment: What might be better is to have both `TransferHandler`s calling a common method which is then used to handle the actual application of the transfer, but that all depends on what it is you're hoping to achieve...

Comment: That was sad. I'm working on two systems where I can drag objects from the main system and then drop them on mxGraph (https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx). The problem is that the mxGraph has its own transferhandler. I wish to drop my objects on my wrapper of mxGraph which will then create the objects for the mxGraph but the transferhandler of mxGraph is triggered instead.